# Allow connections from ECS to an existing RDS database?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm currently trying to identify an existing MySQL instance and I want to allow my ECS deployment to be able to connect to it.

The progress so far is the following:

```js
    const rdsPrimaryDatabase = rds.DatabaseInstance.fromDatabaseInstanceAttributes(this, 'ApplicationReadWrite', {
      instanceEndpointAddress: "application_database_ewqqqrqw.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com", port: 3305, securityGroups: [],
      instanceIdentifier: 'application_database'
    });

    const securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'ApplicationEcsSecurityGroup', {
      vpc: vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: true,
      securityGroupName: 'ApplicationEcsSecurityGroup',
    })

    securityGroup.connections.allowTo(rdsPrimaryDatabase, 3306, 'Primary Database')
```

The above is currently resulting in the following error, related to the last line:

```sh
    Argument of type 'IDatabaseInstance' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IConnectable'.
    The types of 'connections.defaultPort' are incompatible between these types.
```

The error is quite understandable, but I'm unsure as to how to overcome this - as well as I'm not quite sure that I'm doing it the right way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of importing the database instance, try importing the database instance's security group.

```
ISecurityGroup databaseSecurityGroup SecurityGroup.FromSecurityGroupId(scope, "ImportedDatabaseSecurityGroup", securityGroupId, new SecurityGroupImportOptions());

var fargateServiceSecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, "FargateServiceSecurityGroup", new SecurityGroupProps());

databaseSecurityGroup.Connections.AllowFrom(fargateServiceSecurityGroup, Port.AllTcp(), "Allow from fargate security group");
```

Comment: this saved me. I was trying the same thing with an RDS instance and it did not work. Using a security group does work indeed. I really wish CDK would have some way to validate this and warn you or even fail when you do it with RDS instance.

Comment: Why this does not work for me?