# AWS CDK: Can't connect to RDS from FARGATE service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I am new to AWS and AWS CDK in general, I am trying to deploy my stack which consists of POSTGRES(Auora), REDIS(Elastcache) and FARGATE. With few knowledge I have gathered from the internet I have managed to deploy db, cache with exception for Fargate. I can't start service because I cant connect to database.

I believe there is something I am missing on how to allow my fargate to connect to database and I just can't figure it how.

Here is my code how I do it.

```
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as elc from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticache';
import * as ecs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as rds from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-rds';
import * as ecs_patterns from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs-patterns';
import * as ecr_assets from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecr-assets';
import {Construct} from 'constructs';
import * as sm from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-secretsmanager';
import * as logs from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-logs";
import * as path from 'path';

enum Stage {
    LIVE = "live",
    TEST = "test"
}

export class CdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const stage: Stage = Stage.TEST

        const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, `${stage}-vpc`, {
            vpcName: `${stage}-vpc`,
            maxAzs: 3, // Default is all AZs in region
            natGateways: 0,
            subnetConfiguration: [
                {
                    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
                    name: 'public-subnet'
                },
                {
                    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
                    name: 'private-subnet'
                }
            ]
        });

        // const fargateSecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, `fargate-${stage}-security-group`, {
        //     vpc: vpc,
        //     allowAllOutbound: true
        // })

        // create a security group for aurora db
        const dbSecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, `db-security-group-${stage}`, {
            vpc: vpc, // use the vpc created above
            allowAllOutbound: true, // allow outbound traffic to anywhere
        })

        const dbPort = 5432

        // allow inbound traffic from anywhere to the db
        dbSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
            ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(),
            ec2.Port.tcp(dbPort), // allow inbound traffic on port 5432 (postgres)
            'allow inbound traffic from anywhere to the db on port 5432'
        )

        const secret = sm.Secret.fromSecretNameV2(this, "prod", "prod")
        const dbName = "project"

        const databaseCluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, `database-${stage}-cluster`, {
            clusterIdentifier: `${stage}-db`,
            engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres({
                version: rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_15_2
            }),
            credentials: rds.Credentials.fromSecret(secret),
            instances: 1,
            defaultDatabaseName: dbName,
            port: dbPort,
            instanceProps: {
                vpc: vpc,
                instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('serverless'),
                autoMinorVersionUpgrade: true,
                publiclyAccessible: true,
                securityGroups: [dbSecurityGroup],
                vpcSubnets: vpc.selectSubnets({
                    subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC, // use the public subnet created above for the db
                }),
                enablePerformanceInsights: true,
            },
            deletionProtection: false,
            cloudwatchLogsRetention: logs.RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK,
        });

        cdk.Aspects.of(databaseCluster).add({
            visit(node) {
                if (node instanceof rds.CfnDBCluster) {
                    node.serverlessV2ScalingConfiguration = {
                        minCapacity: 1,
                        maxCapacity: 1,
                    }
                }
            },
        })

        const subnetsForRedis = vpc.publicSubnets.map((subnet) => subnet.subnetId)

        const redisSubnetGroup = new elc.CfnSubnetGroup(
            this,
            `redis-cluster-private-subnet-group-${stage}`,
            {
                cacheSubnetGroupName: `redis-private-subnet-group-${stage}`,
                subnetIds: subnetsForRedis,
                description: `redis subnet group for ${stage}`
            }
        )

        const redis = new elc.CfnCacheCluster(this, `${stage}-cache-cluster`, {
            cacheNodeType: "cache.t2.micro",
            engine: "redis",
            numCacheNodes: 1,
            clusterName: `${stage}-redis-cache`,
            cacheSubnetGroupName: redisSubnetGroup.ref,
            vpcSecurityGroupIds: [vpc.vpcDefaultSecurityGroup],
        });

        redis.addDependency(redisSubnetGroup)

        const taskIamRole = new cdk.aws_iam.Role(this, `app-${stage}-role`, {
            roleName: `app-${stage}-role`,
            assumedBy: new cdk.aws_iam.ServicePrincipal('ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com'),
        });

        const taskDefinition = new ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(this, `${stage}-task`, {
            taskRole: taskIamRole,
        });

        secret.grantRead(taskIamRole)

        const root = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..');
        const imageAsset = new ecr_assets.DockerImageAsset(this, "image", {
            directory: root,
            file: "Dockerfile",
        })

        const image = ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(imageAsset);

        taskDefinition.addContainer(`${stage}-container`, {
            image: image,
            portMappings: [{
                containerPort: 7373,
                protocol: ecs.Protocol.TCP
            }],
            logging: ecs.LogDrivers.awsLogs({
                streamPrefix: `${stage}-task`,
                logRetention: logs.RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK,
            }),
            secrets: {
                "DB_PASSWORD": ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(secret, "password"),
                "DB_USER": ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(secret, "username"),
            },
            environment: {
                "DB_HOST": databaseCluster.clusterEndpoint.hostname,
                "DB_PORT": databaseCluster.clusterEndpoint.port.toString(),
                "DB_NAME": dbName,
                "REDIS_ADDRESS": `${redis.attrRedisEndpointAddress}:${redis.attrRedisEndpointPort}`,
            },
        });

        const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, `${stage}-cluster`, {
            clusterName: `${stage}-cluster`,
            vpc: vpc,
            containerInsights: true,
        })

        // Create a load-balanced Fargate service and make it public
        new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, `fargate-service-${stage}`, {
            cluster: cluster,
            cpu: 1024, // Default is 256
            memoryLimitMiB: 2048, // Default is 512
            taskDefinition: taskDefinition,
            desiredCount: 1,
            serviceName: `${stage}-app`,
            assignPublicIp: true,
            publicLoadBalancer: true,
            circuitBreaker: {
                rollback: true
            },
            //securityGroups: [fargateSecurityGroup],
            maxHealthyPercent: 200,
            minHealthyPercent: stage === Stage.TEST ? 0 : 100, // speed up deployment in dev testing
            openListener: true,
        })

        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314584/allow-connections-from-ecs-to-an-existing-rds-database
        databaseCluster.connections.allowFrom(cluster, ec2.Port.tcp(dbPort), "Allow from fargate cluster")
    }
}
```

Using the above codes my console keeps printing

```
Stack CdkStack has an ongoing operation in progress and is not stable (CREATE_IN_PROGRESS)
```

and when I look into service logs see service prints there is database connection issue.

For now I want db to be accessable from anywhere so that I can seed my database from my local machine. But after that only fargate should have access. How to do that

Comment: Does it actually succeed after taking hours? Do you see the service restarting more than once during that time? It should absolutely not take anywhere near that long, and actually the time it takes for private versus public repository image shouldn't be any different at all. I would suggest doing some investigation to verify the task is actually taking that long to start, or if something else is happening, like it is failing health checks and being restarted many times.

Comment: @MarkB From github action I always endup with token expiration error as my task role was limited for 1 hour. From my terminal I always get TIMEOUT error.
I will just re-execute it and comeback with error itself. 
I am having trouble finding logs that can be useful to me. I will try again and see what i will get

Comment: You should be able to watch the ECS console, especially the Tasks tab for your cluster, during a deployment, to see what is happening. In here, may sure you look at both running and stopped tasks, to see if tasks are being restarted. You could also watch the targets in your load balancer's target group during a deployment. It looks like you should also have container logs in CloudWatch Logs that should indicate what is happening inside the containers.

Comment: @MarkB Here is the final error I get before github action terminates `Could not load credentials from ChainableTemporaryCredentials2: The security token included in the request is expired (code=CredentialsError)` It came out after 1 hour

Comment: @MarkB I realized I am having problem connecting to RDS from logs. The problem could be in how I use security groups. Any tips with this will be helpful while I am learning this things

Comment: The security group of the RDS instance should allow incoming requests, on the appropriate port, from the security group of the ECS instance.

Comment: @MarkB I have updated the question, Can you point me on how I should fix security groups?

Comment: `databaseCluster.connections.allowDefaultPortFrom(cluster);` should be enough.

Comment: @gshpychka would you help me with redis too. Now it is the problem

Comment: The code in the question `databaseCluster.connections.allowFrom(cluster, ec2.Port.tcp(dbPort), "Allow from fargate cluster")` should have worked too.

Comment: @gshpychka Thanks. any hint on redis?

Comment: Amend the question with the problem that's left